# substr function with macro variable name

Tags: macros, sas

I am trying to use substr function in SAS macros like this:

```
%let hg=Name;
data gg_;
set sashelp.class; 
gh=%substr(&hg,1,3);
run;
```

and also I tried

```
data gg_;
set sashelp.class; 
gh=%sysfunc(substr(&hg,1,3));
run;
```

Here `Name` is the variable in `sashelp.class`

But I do not get the first three chars from `Name` variable into `gh`. 
How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing macro and data step logic.
Since it is a data step, use the SUBSTR() function, not %substr. If the macro variable consists of the text you want to extract then quote it, otherwise leave the macro variable unquoted.

```
gh=substr(&hg, 1, 3);
```

Note: edited to reflect comment.

Comment: I think he meant for the macro variable to contain the name of the variable that is to be used in the SUBSTR() function call.  So remove the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a dataset inside a macro function then you want to use the normal sas function so you just need to use `substr()` instead of `%substr()`.

```
%let hg=Name;
data gg_;
set sashelp.class; 
gh=substr(&hg,1,3);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `gh=`, try %`let gh = ....`

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post. Also, do leave things as "thanks" and salutations with names out of SO. This is a technical site, where personal writings have no place.

Comment: Apart from adding the recommended explanation, please learn about formatting, https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting , I am pretty sure that you did not intend your code to look like that, maybe even the syntax is broken (even if by a helpfully minded fellow user.... @Adriaan cough, cough ...).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you write code that uses macro variable names which reflect their use.

For instance

`dsvar` would indicated the macro variable is for use as a DATA step variable.

```
  %let dsvar = name ;

  data gg_;
    set sashelp.class; 
    &dsvar._first3 = substr(&dsvar,1,3) ;
  run;
```